# customize beans in spring boot MVC test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am using Spring-boot 1.4.0.RELEASE. Have constructed a MVC int test as suggested at

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests

However, I cannot find a good way to customize the objectMapper there. In my production configuration, I have the Bean annotated with @Primary. There is some customization with the objectmapper defined there and I really want to include that configuration in my MVC test. But I cannot find a good way to do so.

Would be very grateful if anyone can shed some light there

Comment: So you have a customized `ObjectMapper` that you want used to deserialize your request or serialize the response?  If so, you will need to do more configuration than what is illustrated in that example.

Answer (score 0):

Use @TestConfiguration to configure your objectmapper according to your needs in integration tests